# Unable to authenticate with OAuth 20. with JSON

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-workspace, service-accounts, google-apis-explorer

I have been trying to make API calls to the Google Admin SDK with a service account using Python.

But I can not authenticate correctly.

Here's my code:

```
import google.auth
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import requests

# Carga el archivo JSON de la cuenta de servicio
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    '**********************************************',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'])

# Si el token ha expirado, refresca el token
if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
    creds.refresh(Request())

# Obtén el token de acceso
token = creds.token

# Parámetros de la solicitud
domain = 'baldiri.info'

# Construye la URL de la solicitud
url = f'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer&domain={domain}'

# Usa el token en tus solicitudes de API
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Imprime la respuesta
print(response.json())
```

> Error:
>
> {'error': {'code': 401, 'message': 'Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.'](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%27), 'errors': [{'message': 'Invalid Credentials', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'authError', 'location': 'Authorization', 'locationType': 'header'}], 'status': 'UNAUTHENTICATED'}}

- The Google service account has the permissions to the admin SDK.
- The json corresponds to the service account.
- In the workspace console I have added the service account for the domain delegation.
- I attach the method I want to use:
  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list

The parameters that I need to add to the request are:

1. customer=my_customer
2. Domain= a list of domains

From the google explorer API I have been able to make calls of this type annex capture of the application

[image]

Being able to make the api call to obtain the list of users of the domains that hang from my reseller.